# java fetching json string to class object type not working

Tags: java, spring

In my java-Spring mvc project I  have (valid) **json string**,like:

```
[{
    "name": "sonia",
    "emails": [{
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "type": "Work"
    }, {
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "type": "office"
    }]    
}]
```

I have **Email** class:

```
public class Email 
{

  private String email;
  private String type;
//setters & getters

}
```

**User** Class

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String name;
private Set<Email> emails;
//setters and getters

}
```

I want to jetch json string to my class object type from Above String it will like

```
sonia
abc@gmail.com
Work

sonia
xyz@gmail.com
Work
```

So,I have tried the code below:

```
    try {

    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(JsonString);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    User[] users = gson.fromJson(jsonarray.toString(), User[].class);

    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

    //fetches name
    logger.info(users[i].getName());

    //here I want to fetch user with email/emails

    logger.info(users[i].getEmails());
   //but not getting results

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Contact save > Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

For one user I want to receive their emails..but here I am not getting result..what I have to add to achieve my requirement.

I am getting errors:

```
 INFO | 0 
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0 
 INFO | 0 
...
...
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: If there are no annotations it might be the use of generics, i.e. GSON probably doesn't know that the set contains objects of type `Email`. Due to type erasure the generic types are normally not available at runtime - except in reflection data, so it still might be available in the field metadata, though I'm not sure about that and I don't know what GSON makes of it. Did you try `Email[]` instead as a test?

Comment: errors:
INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0
 INFO | 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think that you are trying to map json to wrong objects. Take your json and post it [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) then you should update your objects. I think that you should have after it something like below:

Email class:

```
public class Email { 
    private String email;
    private String type;
    }
```

User class:

```
public class User{

private String name;

private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();
}
```

Use `ObjectMapper` here is [reference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to documentation. And then have a look at the [example by MKyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) how to use

Answer (score 0):

This is working solution, you can tune your code accordingly:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String jsonString = "[{\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"sonia\",\n" +
            "    \"emails\": [{\n" +
            "        \"email\": \"abc@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"Work\"\n" +
            "    }, {\n" +
            "        \"email\": \"xyz@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "        \"type\": \"office\"\n" +
            "    }]    \n" +
            "}]";
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("name", "sonia");
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject jsonObject1 = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject1.addProperty("email", "abc@gmail.com");
    jsonObject1.addProperty("type", "Work");
    JsonObject jsonObject2 = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject2.addProperty("email", "xyz@gmail.com");
    jsonObject2.addProperty("type", "office");
    jsonArray.add(jsonObject1);
    jsonArray.add(jsonObject2);
    jsonObject.add("emails", jsonArray);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    JsonArray jsonArray1 = new JsonArray();
    jsonArray1.add(jsonObject);
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    User[] users = gson.fromJson(jsonArray1, User[].class);

    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(users[i].getName());
        System.out.print(users[i].getEmails().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I think you mean to get the *Set*'s elements

```
 for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

 Set<Email> tempEmail = users[i].getEmails();
 Object [] tempEmailObj = tempEmail .toArray();
 Email[] email = Arrays.copyOf(tempEmailObj , tempEmailObj .length, Email[].class);
 String nemail = email[0].getEmail();

 //fetch name
  logger.info(users[i].getName());


//fetch user with email
 logger.info(nemail);
 }
```

And put also

```
public Set<Email> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }
```

in the *User* class